# How to make div follow when scrolling AngularJS

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

In my AngularJS project i have a search bar on top of the page.when user searched something,result will display below to search bar.user can scroll down on the result.what i'm trying to do is,when user scroll down,search bar should follow.i found [JQuery code](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvwh3box/1/).but i want it in AngularJS.how can i convert this in to AngularJS or is there another easy solution?

```
<div id="p_search">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search Here" ng-model="query.name" />
            <select class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="All Cetegories" ng-model="query.category">
              <option ng-repeat="option in categories" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.category}}</option>
                </select>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-purple btn-lg" type="submit" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

My Controller

```
myApp.controller('PController', function ($scope, $http, $window, Common, localStorageService) {

});
```

Comment: the simplest solution would be to use `position:fixed` and fix the search bar to the position where you want so even when the user scrolls it will remain at the same position. or do you want it to animate?

Comment: i've tested `css position :fixed`.but i want my div move smoothly like above jQuery example.yes with animation.

Comment: you can just put the same jQuery code into your controller. And add "follow-scroll" class to search box.

Comment: @BanshiL.Dangi i tried to add jQuery code in to my controller.but i havn't solve.can you show me how to add that jQuery in to my controller?

Answer (score 0):

I had created an example [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BUPxT0?p=preview) which might help you kind of similar example. You might have to change some style to position the sticky part at certain place.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl($scope, $http, $window, $document, $timeout) {
  var ctop = 0;
  var sectionArr = [];

  var initEvents = function() {
    //delaying for dom height calculation
    $timeout(function() {
      angular.forEach($scope.blocks, function(data, index) {
        var s = angular.element($document[0].getElementById('block-' + index))[0];
        sectionArr[index] = {
          top: s.offsetTop,
          height: (s.offsetHeight + s.offsetTop)
        };
      });
    }, 200);

    //attaching event for scrolling
    angular.element($window).off('scroll').on('scroll', function(ev) {
      var scrollOffsetTop = ev.pageY || ($window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? $window.pageYOffset : ($document[0].documentElement || $document[0].body.parentNode || $document[0].body).scrollTop;
      var gabBetween = 1;
      angular.forEach(sectionArr, function(data, id) {
        var head = angular.element($document[0].getElementById('header-' + id));
        if (scrollOffsetTop > data.top && scrollOffsetTop < data.height) {
          if (scrollOffsetTop > (data.height - head[0].clientHeight) && scrollOffsetTop < data.height) {
            head.addClass('absolute')
              .removeClass('fixed')
              .css('top', (data.height - (data.top + head[0].clientHeight) - gabBetween) + 'px');
          } else {
            head.addClass('fixed')
              .removeClass('absolute')
              .css('top', 0);
          }
        } else {
          head.removeClass('fixed')
            .removeClass('absolute')
            .removeAttr('style');
        }
      });
    });
  };

  //initializing for fetching json
  var init = function() {
    $scope.blocks = [{
      "header": "Header First",
      "content": "Header First with content............. First Header"
    }, {
      "header": "Header Second",
      "content": "Header Second with content............. Second Header"
    }, {
      "header": "Header Third",
      "content": "Header Third with content............. Third Header"
    }, {
      "header": "Header Fourth",
      "content": "Header Fourth with content............. Fourth Header"
    }, {
      "header": "Header Fifth",
      "content": "Header Fifth with content............. Fifth Header"
    }, {
      "header": "Header Sixth",
      "content": "Header Sixth with content............. Sixth Header"
    }, {
      "header": "Header Seventh",
      "content": "Header Seventh with content............. Seventh Header"
    }];
    //events attachment occurs after fetching data
    initEvents();
  };

  //starting
  init();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #efefef;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', verdana;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 700px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section>header {
  display: block;
  min-height: 75px;
}

header>div {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fe001a;
  background: rgba(254, 0, 26, 0.8);
  padding: 5px 25px;
}

header>.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

header>.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0
}

section>p {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 25px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body data-ng-app="app" data-ng-cloak>
  <h2>Sticky Header</h2>
  <p>Checkout example of each section making a sticky header</p>
  <main data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <section data-ng-repeat="data in blocks" id="block-{{$index}}">
      <header>
        <div id="header-{{$index}}">
          <h3>{{data.header}}<span style="float:right">#{{$index+1}}</span></h3>
        </div>
      </header>
      <p data-ng-bind="data.content"></p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: @Tje123 If you need one followable box then my answer might not be the correct one. Please comment soon so that I can delete before people start down-voting. If you need dynamic sticky boxes following then you can reuse part of it.